# Python functioning interactive menu

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement an interactive text menu to simplify some of my larger code executions and am having trouble figuring out how I would structure it to be fully functional. Right now I have a main menu, 2 sub-menus, and a quit function. I need the sub menus to execute the specific code I have (which I will tie-in later), but I wrote it in a way where the options 1 and 2 will always go to my two sub-menus, no matter where I am in my menu. What is the best way to code this so that if I have selected 1 for the first option that I am met with other options for those #1 or #2 spots? I obviously need to get rid of the constant values for 1 and 2, but I am unsure how I would make it work the way I need it to.

```
import time, sys, os

    # Main definition - constants
    menu_actions = {}


    ##Menu Functions

    def main_menu():
        os.system('cls')
        print ""
        print 30 * "-", "MENU", 30 * "-"
        print "1. Batch Deployment"
        print "2. Single Deployment"
        print "3. List Tickets"
        print "0. Exit/Quit"
        print 66 * "-"
        print ""
        choice = raw_input(" Make a selection from the menu >>   ")
        exec_menu(choice)


    def batch_menu():
        os.system('cls')
        print "Batch Deployment\n"

        print "1. Run All In Progress Sonic Deployments"
        print "9. Back"
        print "0. Quit"
        print ""
        choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
        exec_menu(choice)
        return


    def ticket_menu():
        os.system('cls')
        print "Choose Task to Deploy...\n"

        print "9. Back"
        print "0. Quit"
        print ""
        choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
        exec_menu(choice)
        return


    def exec_menu(choice):
        os.system('cls')
        ch = choice.lower()
        if ch == '':
            menu_actions['main_menu']()
        else:
            try:
                menu_actions[ch]()
            except KeyError:
                print "Invalid selection, please try again.\n"
                time.sleep(3)
                menu_actions['main_menu']()
        return


    def back():
        menu_actions['main_menu']()

    # Menu definition
    menu_actions = {
        'main_menu': main_menu,
        '1': batch_menu,
        '2': ticket_menu,
        '9': back,
        '0': exit, }

    # Menu Logic

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Launch main menu
        main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking this answered because I eventually figured it out. The logic for the menu branching off was added to the main_menu function, I left the constants of back and exit in there because I would like them to be the same throughout the menu.